# Dynamically setting the backgroundImage style propery based on graphql query results

Tags: gatsby

- I am trying to create a hero section like in Gatsby, where the background image of the hero section is loaded dynamically from the returned query of Graphql. The image url as I understand should be on `post.feature-image`.
- Now I put that in the code below and it simply doesn't work. I tried all the possible variations like removing the $ sign/brackets/etc. to adapt it to my needs and still didn't work or show anything.
- As far as I can see, this is not a simple ReactJS usage of the `backgroundImage` style property, as it has a Graphql value returned to be the url value for the backgroundImage style property.

```js
function Hero() {
    return (
       <div  styles={{ backgroundImage:`url(${post.feature-image})` }}>
           <h1>This is a hero section title here!</h1>
       </div>
    );
}
        
export default Hero;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are fetching properly the image URL, the style object is named `style`, not `styles` (spot the ending S) as you sample shows.

```
function Hero() {
    return (
       <div  style={{ backgroundImage:`url(${post.feature-image})` }}>
           <h1>This is a hero section title here!</h1>
       </div>
    );
}
        
export default Hero;
```

You can check [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style) for further details.